# nuxt request error unhandled 500 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getHeader')

Tags: header, nuxt.js, prisma, setcookie

when im trying to setup a set cookie in my first-time project using nuxt and Prisma, is gives me an error that says Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getHeader') and i don't know what's wrong with my code

`my login auth`

```js
import { sendError } from 'h3'
import { createUser } from '~~/server/db/users'
import { userTransformer } from '~~/server/transformer/user'
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const body = await useBody(event)

    const { username, email, password, repeatPassword, name } = body

    if (!username || !email || !password || !repeatPassword || !name) {
        return sendError(event, createError({
            statusCode: 400, statusMessage: "Invalid params"
        }))
    }

    if (password !== repeatPassword) {
        return sendError(event, createError({
            statusCode: 400, statusMessage: "Password not match"
        }))
    }

    const userData = {
        username, email, password, name, profileImage: 'https://picsum.photos/200/200'
    }

    const user = await createUser(userData)
    return {
        body: userTransformer(user)
    }
})
```

`my setcookie function`

```js
export const sendRefreshToken = (event:any, token:any) => {
    setCookie(event.res, "refresh_token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: true
    })
}
```

Comment: ok I fix the problem but I am still confused, what is the difference between event and event.res?

Comment: You might want to ask this in Nuxt GitHub Discussions as they might be able to answer the query better. What actually is event.res could be identified by looking at the signature of setCookie function. https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/discussions

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same.

The error comes from `nuxt-root.vue`, so I looked up the transformed code with `VITE_NODE_DEBUG_DUMP=true pnpm dev`

The snippet of the error code
in `nuxt3/dist/app/components/nuxt-root.vue:76:16` is:

```
// ...
// L72
const __vite_ssr_import_5__ = await __vite_ssr_import__("vue");

const _sfc_setup = _sfc_main.setup
_sfc_main.setup = (props, ctx) => {
  const ssrContext = __vite_ssr_import_5__.useSSRContext()
  ;(ssrContext.modules || (ssrContext.modules = new Set())).add("../node_modules/.pnpm/nuxt3@3.1.1-rc.0-27911047.7d812db/node_modules/nuxt3/dist/app/components/nuxt-root.vue")
  return _sfc_setup ? _sfc_setup(props, ctx) : undefined
}
const __vite_ssr_import_6__ = await __vite_ssr_import__("/@id/__x00__plugin-vue:export-helper");
```

It seems the server did not run in Vue SSR context, where `useSSRContext()` returns undefined. This also matches the previous errors in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.
[Vue warn]: Server rendering context not provided. Make sure to only call useSSRContext() conditionally in the server build.
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function
```

In that sense, disabling SSR would bypass this error:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false
})
```

Haven't dive deep into this, but hopefully, this could provide a bit more context.